# AppScript onEdit simple function appears to be running slow

Tags: google-apps-script, eventtrigger

In AppScript it is difficult to get the `last modified date` of a single cell. One can get the historical values via the revisions of the sheet itself. This is not a straightforward task. Tracking the `last modified date` via a `onEdit` scheduled functions seems like an easier solution to deploy.

I have the following script that attempts to do this. Note that it tries to avoid calling the `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` step as much as possible. I assume that doing so is slow. However, despite my attempt at optimization this script still takes about 36 seconds to complete. Is this just the way things are or have I missed a crucial part on the script that is to blame for such long runtimes? Any ideas on optimizing the speed of this function will be greatly appreciated. It is going to be deployed to a sheet that has multiple users working on it.

```
function onEdit(event){
  Logger.log('Edit event detected.');
  if (event.range.getSheet().getName() !== 'Reference Number Generator'){
    Logger.log('Edit event not relevant: different sheet');
    return null;
  }
  if (event.range.getColumn()!== 13){
    Logger.log('Edit event not relevant: different column');
    return null;
  }
  if (event.value !== 'Yes'){
    Logger.log('Edit event not relevant: not changed to YES');
    return null;
  }
  Logger.log(`Logging change to row ${event.range.getRow()}`);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reference Number Generator');

  var date =  new Date();
  sheet.getRange(event.range.getRow(),16).setValue(date);
  Logger.log('...done!')
}
```

### Response to comments

Thank you very much @dataful.tech for the insights and debugging suggestions. I have the following answers to the queries which I think are useful to include in the body of the question.

1. **Is it persistent?** On average, the function takes about 36 seconds. Sometimes longer. This is always the case. It also times out.
2. **Please send screenshot of the delay**. I have attached a screenshot of the logs. It seems that it lags after logging "Edit event detected" and only gets to one of the case statements much later. To me that suggests an issue with `event.range` and its related class methods such as `getSheet()`. These are probably retrieving a lot.
3. **Are there any formulas in the data**? No formulas, only dropdown boxes for the user to select on of the available options.
4. **How big is the document**? It is probably quite large at 22,478 rows and 25 columns.

I think that step 4 might be the case and that very little could be done about that.

[image: runtime logs1]

[image]

### Logging: identifying the bottleneck

I followed the suggestions that @dataful.tech have after the above section. The renaming of the function to anything that is not `onEdit` significantly reduced the amount of timeouts. The function remains the same thought. Following the next suggestion to log all steps, the following script was executed. I included `event.value` as a sanity check even though it does not call anything.

```
function test(event){
  Logger.log('event.range.getSheet()...');
  var sheet = event.range.getSheet();
  Logger.log('..done!');

  Logger.log('sheet.getName()...');
  sheet.getName();
  Logger.log('..done!');

  Logger.log('event.range.getColumn()...');
  event.range.getColumn();
  Logger.log('..done!');

  Logger.log('event.value...');
  event.value;
  Logger.log('..done!');

  Logger.log('event.range.getRow()...');
  event.range.getRow();
  Logger.log('..done!');
}
```

The script produced the following logs that expose `sheet.getName()` to be the bottleneck. How very strange. It was intended to actually be a form of optimization such that we can reject edits that are not on the relevant worksheet. I am quite curious was to why retrieving the name might take so long. I think that all of this perhaps reinforces the quote by Donald Knuth: "Premature optimization is root of all evil!"

[image]

Comment: I have tried your formula and it finishes in 1-2 seconds.  There is a change or two to optimize it by nothing to explain 36 seconds. Some questions: (1) is it persistent - always so long? (2) can you share a screenshot of the execution log with the log messages, please.  It should show on which step the delay happens. (3) Do you have any formulas consuming the data in col 16 where the function writes to? (a sample document will help to understand you setup) (4) How big is the document approximately (several thousand vs hundreds of thousand rows).

Comment: Most probably, you have a really big spreadsheet

Comment: @dataful.tech I have answered your questions in the body of the question itself due to the value that it adds. Thank you for the insights. As TheMaster suggests, it is most likely due to it being a large spreadsheet. I don't think there is much of a way around that.

Comment: @DylanSolms Thank you for your answers. Based on the logs, it looks like it spends a lot of time on `event.range.getSheet().getName()` which is strange.  Some suggestions: 1. Rename the function to something other than `onEdit`: it runs twice on each edit (installable + simple trigger).  2. Copy the document and check if it repeats in a new one.  3. Comment `setValue(date)` and then comment out conditions one by one to see if all of them are slow or only `event.range.getSheet()`. This should give you more info on the issue.

Comment: @dataful.tech I have changed the name of the function and Logged each method call. It turns out that `getName()` is the bottleneck. I find this quite bizarre. It was meant to optimize the function by rejecting edits that did not pertain to the relevant sheet but turned out being the problem. How is that for "premature optimization is root of all evil".

Comment: @DylanSolms Thank you for posting experiments results.  Yes, this is very unusual.  I would expect to see some delays with `getSheet()` but not with `getName()`.  Maybe using `sheet.getSheetId()` instead of  `getName()` will be faster? ([docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetid))

Comment: @dataful.tech `sheet.getSheetId()` runs almost instantly as one would expect. It is thus a fine replacement for `sheet.getName()`. Thank you very much for you patient assistance and guidance. I believe that you have answered my question and solved the problem: the new code does exactly what the old one should but only magnitudes faster.

Comment: How many sheets do you have?

Comment: For future reference, 1. Present logs as text and avoid "only" screenshots data 2. Use `console.time` instead of `Logger`

Comment: @TheMaster I have about 10 worksheets on the Google sheet. There are several people working on the Google sheet. The worksheet for which I am using the `onEdit` function operates on a worksheet that does not receive the most editing. As such, I thought it might be a good idea to reject edits that do not occur to this sheet. This can now be done via `sheet.getSheetId()`.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for suggesting logs as text as well as the use of `console.time`. I was not aware of `console.time` and am keen to read its docs and then try it out. In hindsight, I can see now that the screenshots are rather awkward looking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know you are on the right sheet from this line of code:

```
if (event.range.getSheet().getName() !== 'Reference Number Generator'){
```

Try this:

```
function onEdit(event){
  Logger.log('Edit event detected.');
  let sheet = event.range.getSheet();
  if ( sheet.getName() !== 'Reference Number Generator'){
    Logger.log('Edit event not relevant: different sheet');
    return null;
  }
  if (event.range.getColumn()!== 13){
    Logger.log('Edit event not relevant: different column');
    return null;
  }
  if (event.value !== 'Yes'){
    Logger.log('Edit event not relevant: not changed to YES');
    return null;
  }
  Logger.log(`Logging change to row ${event.range.getRow()}`);

  var date =  new Date();
  sheet.getRange(event.range.getRow(),16).setValue(date);
  Logger.log('...done!')
}
```